# Is Automator intended to create distributable stand-alone apps?

Tags: automator

I have a series of executables which I would like to wrap into a stand-alone .app. A bit like ffmpegx does for the executables contained under its /Resources folder.
I've noticed that Automator allows you to create a stand-alone application, but it's not clear to me how to:

- include my executables within the .app package
- specify a **relative** path when adding a "run shell script" action, so I can execute my executables when the user double clicks the .app

Is Automator intended to be used as "application maker" or should I use something else? If Automator is the way to go, how can I solve the two above issues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really designed for this, but I think you can hack it to do what you'd like.

First, to get the relative path to the .app package, you'll want to add a **Run AppleScript** action before your shell script. The code for the AppleScript should be something like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
   set p to POSIX path of (path to me)
   return {p}
end run
```

That will pass the path to your .app bundle to your shell script action as an argument. Just set the **Run Shell Script** to pass input *as arguments* and you should be set to use the path in your shell script however you need to:
[image: Script action settings]

Once that's done, you can package whatever executables you need in the *Contents/Resources* folder of the .app bundle. You can get there in the Finder by right/command-clicking the .app and selecting *Show Package Contents*.

**Important Note:** Automator rewrites the .app bundle every time you save it, so you'll have to add the executables again every time *after* you make a change.

Answer (score 1):

Automator really isn't the right tool for this job. Instead, I suggest you look into AppleScriptObjC, which is one of the project types you can create using Xcode. You'll find help with AppleScriptObjC over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript-objc).